# Variable inside a method is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a game with tkinter and for that I used classes to be the frames so I can change screens...
My class Jogo is the game and I want to put a clock with a countdown in it. The code for the clock that I made just for test, without using classes works. However when I tried to put it on the game's code a problem appear

```
NameError: name 'countVar' is not defined
```

Here's the code that I want to fix:

```
class Jogo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        countVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)

        clock = tk.Label(self, textvariable=countVar)
        clock.grid()

    def update_clock(self, event = None):
        for t in range(120, -1, -1):
            mins, secs = divmod(t,60)
            timeformat = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(mins, secs)
            countVar.set(timeformat)
            clock.update_idletasks()
            sleep(1)
```

And the code that I made without using classes:

```
import tkinter
from time import sleep

main = tkinter.Tk()
count = tkinter.StringVar()
txt = tkinter.Label(main, textvariable=count)
txt.grid()

def update_txt(event = None):
    for t in range(120, -1, -1):
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        count.set(timeformat)
        txt.update_idletasks()
        sleep(1)

main.after(1000,update_txt)
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your example without classes the `count` variable is in a scope that is available to your `update_txt` function.

In your class, the `update_clock` function does not have access to the `countVar` variable that you define in `__init__`. Two functions defined separately will not have access to each others variables. This is what you use your variable `self` for. The first argument passed to any of your functions in this class is a copy of the class, and you give it the name `self`.

So if you set it as `self.countVar` it will be available in `update_clock` as `self.countVar`.

You may be interested in doing a search for "python LEGB", which will show you a bit more about how scoping works in python :D

Comment: Thank you. I'll search for it.

Answer (score 0):

`countVar` is just a local variable, in both methods. It is not an attribute on you class, so setting `countVar` in `__init__` is entirely independent from `countVar` in `update_clock`.

Make it an attribute by setting it on `self`:

```
self.countVar = tk.StringVar()
```

Now you can access it in `update_clock`.

Note that this also applies to the `clock` variable. Put everything you need to share between methods (the instance *state*) on `self`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot... Got another problem but for now i'll try to fix it by my own.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique: glad to have been on help!